# How do PHP and Apache handle uploaded files?

Tags: php, apache, upload

I am working on some PHP upload code.

When I call the copy function it will start a thread in incremental mod. I want to read the full details of the upload functionality for apache and PHP. In fact, I want implementation details for this functionality, namely:

- How a file is copied in temp folder
- How it is copied to the proper destination
- What happens when server is busy and client is sending fix size of chunks

I am trying to upload file from my Android application. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6533517/741174) code for uploading. But my most of the files header are changed. Most of my uploaded files' sizes increase. Why its happen? In fact I want to investigate it. My client is Android application and server is apache 2.0 with php 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help a lot if you explain **why** you need to know how Apache and PHP handle uploaded files so people can give more specific answers. One should usually not have to bother with these details, it's the beauty of abstraction. You simply get a $_FILES array, and call `move_uploaded_file()` if you want to store it permanently, no matter in how many chunks it was uploaded or how busy the server was when it was receiving the file. If you for example simply want to display a progress bar for uploading files, there's tons of information on that on the web.

Comment: @CodeCaster +1 talk about going far far fetched

Answer (score 0):

CodeCaster allready gave part of the answer...

Just a really big tip here, php.net has a huge database with ALL of the functions and great examples that goes with them.

This is the main page about handling file uploads (just a table of contents) https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Here is pretty much everything you need to know:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

W3Schools also has a tutorial on this.
http://w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp