# Out of Memory exception in android app video uploading

Tags: android, video, upload, out-of-memory, heap-memory

My App getting out of memory exception as `"Failed to allocate a 94716684 byte allocation with 16773184 free bytes and 59MB until OOM"` ,while converting video to `Base64` string . `Base64` string is the format that i used to upload the video to the server.how i can manage the issue ? how i can upload a video which is almost `35MB`  to the server by following this `Base64` format.
I found in debug mode using memory monitor window at some situation  before `Base64` conversion the allocated memory is around `250MB` and free memory is only 5MB. whether there is a method or tool to investigate what are the things (variables or other) using this 250MB at the debug  point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send Video File directly through MultiPart to server , Base64 string of 35 MB file consumes to much memory .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload video in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533396/upload-video-in-android)

Comment: Thank you Chetan and Neeraj.